# template friend bool overload clash in namespace

Tags: c++, overloading, friend

I have 2 different class templates in the same namespace, xy and rgba. Both of them overload operators == and !=. When I compile, I get the error that the overload has already been defined. Is it because both those classes are in the same namespace? If so, is there a trick to avoid the clash? I tried different labels for the templates, it gave me the same result.

```
template <typename A>
class xy
{
public:

    A x, y;

    xy() :x(0), y(0) {}

    xy(A x, A y) :x(x), y(y) {}

    template<typename B>
    xy& operator = (const B& v) {
        x = A(v.x), y = A(v.y); return*this;
    }

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator == (const B& a, const C& v) {
        return a.x == v.x && a.y == v.y;
    }

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator != (const B& a, const C& v) {
        return a.x != v.x || a.y != v.y;
    }

    template<typename B>
    operator B() const {
        return B(x, y);
    }

};

class rgba
{
public:

    int r, g, b, a;

    rgba() :r(255), g(255), b(255), a(255) {}

    rgba(int r, int g, int b, int a) :r(r), g(g), b(b), a(a) {}

    template<typename B>
    rgba& operator = (const B& v) {
        r = A(v.r), g = A(v.g), r = A(v.b), a = A(v.a); return*this;
    }

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator == (const B& a, const C& v) { // <- already defined ?
        return a.r == v.r && a.g == v.g && a.b == v.b && a.a == v.a;
    }

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator != (const B& a, const C& v) { // <- already defined ?
        return a.r != v.r || a.g != v.g || a.b != v.b || a.a != v.a;
    }

    template<typename B>
    operator B() const {
        return B(r, g, b, a);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are your comparison operators templated? Not to mention the implicit conversions to any type.

Comment: `template<typename B> operatorB()` basically specifies that this type can be converted to any other type in the known universe. This kind of an overload will only end in tears.

Comment: This is a guess, but I think you're looking for forward declarations, not templates.

Comment: a `friend` declaration declares a function external to the class. you do it twice. So, why `friend` at all?

Comment: @cigien I'm using a library with which I'd like to use the native vectors. Sam yeah, that was the idea :D. Thanks Serge, you nailed it

Comment: All your template functions seem, as mentioned, wrong. Instead of e.g. `template<typename B> xy& operator = (const B& v)` you should have `template<typename B> xy& operator =(const xy<B>& v)`. Note the changed argument. Do the same for all functions.

Comment: @Some, yeah, no, not yet, I'll spend some time later to add the real types, but thank you for your concern !

Comment: Doing it "right" from the start will save you a lot of grief in the long run. Right now you can assign to an `xy<A>` object from any unrelated types as long as they have public `x` and `y` member that can be implicitly converted to the type `A`. For example `struct Bad { char x, y; };` can be used to assign to `xy<float>`. Is that really intended?

Comment: @Some, I'm a dangerous man who lives dangerously :D Jokes aside, I may make it safer later, who knows, it's just a study project for now though, thanks for your help ! And yeah, totally intended, I was testing it with some vectors from other libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good points in the comment, so I will only provide a solution to your compilation problem.

You need some `type_traits` and `if constexpr`. If you don't have `c++17` you can do it with `SFINAE`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template <class T, class U = void>
struct has_xy : std::false_type{};

template <class T>
struct has_xy<T, std::void_t<
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().x),
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().y)
                 >
              >: std::true_type{};


template <class T, class U = void>
struct has_rgba : std::false_type{};

template <class T>
struct has_rgba<T, std::void_t<
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().r),
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().g),
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().b),
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().a)
                 >
              >: std::true_type{};

template <typename A>
class xy
{
public:

    A x, y;

    xy() :x(0), y(0) {}

    xy(A x, A y) :x(x), y(y) {}

    template<typename B>
    xy& operator = (const B& v) {
        x = A(v.x), y = A(v.y); return*this;
    }

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator == (const B& a, const C& v);

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator != (const B& a, const C& v);

    template<typename B>
    operator B() const {
        return B(x, y);
    }

};

class rgba
{
public:

    int r, g, b, a;

    rgba() :r(255), g(255), b(255), a(255) {}

    rgba(int r, int g, int b, int a) :r(r), g(g), b(b), a(a) {}

    template<typename B>
    rgba& operator = (const B& v) {
        r = A(v.r), g = A(v.g), r = A(v.b), a = A(v.a); return*this;
    }

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator == (const B& a, const C& v);

    template<typename B, typename C>
    friend bool operator != (const B& a, const C& v);

    template<typename B>
    operator B() const {
        return B(r, g, b, a);
    }
};


template<typename B, typename C>
bool operator == (const B& a, const C& v)
{
    if constexpr ( has_xy<B>::value and has_xy<C>::value )
    {
       return a.x == v.x && a.y == v.y;   
    }
    else if constexpr  ( has_rgba<B>::value and has_rgba<C>::value )
    {
       return a.r == v.r && a.g == v.g && a.b == v.b && a.a == v.a;
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // or throw, or don't compile do as you want   
    }
}

template<typename B, typename C>
bool operator != (const B& a, const C& v)
{
   return not operator==(a,v);
}

int main()
{
    xy<float> x1,x2;
    rgba r1,r2;
    if ( x1 == x2 ) { std::cout << " x1 == x2 " << std::endl; }
    if ( x1 != x2 ) { std::cout << " x1 != x2 " << std::endl; }
    if ( r1 == r2 ) { std::cout << " r1 == r2 " << std::endl; }
    if ( r1 != r2 ) { std::cout << " r1 != r2 " << std::endl; }
    if ( x1 == r2 ) { std::cout << " x1 == r2 " << std::endl; }
    if ( x1 != r2 ) { std::cout << " x1 != r2 " << std::endl; }
}
```

Live demo : [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RVPUeoZLCJJYLDO8)

Both class are friend with the same function, and the function is only declare once outside of the classes.

Then inside the operator, we select, at compile time, if we can compare en `x/y` or on `r/g/b/a`

Comment: wow, merci Martin, c'est complet ! Je comprends rien, un bon challenge du coup :D